# Convert optional string to Int crashes in spite of having value

Tags: swift4

I check the optional string

```
 print(limitCash)
  if let value = Int32(limitCash) {
         aProvider.limitBuy = value
  }
```

The value of limitCash is Optional("500").

The program checks if let statement and skips it without assigning value.

Program crashes if I try aProvider.limitBuy = Int32(limitCash)!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to unwrap String? to String and then unwrap the result of casting from String to UInt32 (that will be Uint32?).

```
print(limitCash)
if let stringValue = limitCash {
   if let value = Int32(stringValue) {
     print(value) // 500
   }
}
```

Comment: I have defined: var limitCash:String =  "N/A"; so if let stringValue = limitCash { gives error - "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'"